# I Found This Error when i try to Connect to Oracle TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: database, oracle

I found this Error when i try to connect to oracle

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

```
C:\Users\Mike Reze>sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Mar 1 14:57:38 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Comment: Does `sqlplus sys/password@your_database as sysdba` work correctly?

Comment: @Littlefoot No it doesnt it will have this Error                                                                                                                                          
`ERROR:`
`ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect`
descriptor

Comment: @MarcoDaniels i tried Every Solution but i didnt find one

Comment: Did you use your database name? That would be something like XE or ORCL or ... whatever it is. Check contents of the TNSNAMES.ORA file, it is written in there. Also, you might need to add a *suffix* (if there's the domain name), such as ORCL.YOUR.DOMAIN.

Comment: yes i did i specified it with my domain name